# How to search mongdb for date string in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: mongodb

I need to search a mongodb collection that contains a date represented in mm/dd/yyyy format.  I need to search for a specific date range.

Comment: Whether or not searching for a date range from a date string is possible will largely depend on what version of MongoDB you're running. If you're using 3.6 or later, please take a look at using the [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator. Otherwise, if 3.4, you will need to use [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to change the format to `yyyy/mm/dd` in order to do a lexicographical range search.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. SO is not a free coding service... What did you try/research?

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelName.aggregate([{
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    date: {
                        $dateToString: {
                            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                            date: '$date'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$match": {
                "_id.date": {
                    $gt: start,//req.query.startDate
                    $lt: end  //req.query.endDate
                },
            }
        }])

try thiss
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer, even if it is right, try to describe your new point of view... not just place a solution